# How can i update a variable after pressing buttons on tkinter?

Tags: python, variables, tkinter

There's an example of my code below.

I am trying to make a GUI with tkinter, in python. I want an app that has a variable, let's say `var_list`, that is introduced into a function as a parameter.I run this function using a button with `command=lambda: analize(var_list)`

I want to be able to modify the variable by pressing buttons (buttons to add strings to the list). And I have a function for that aswell:

```
def button_clicked(e):
    if ((e["text"]).lower()) in var_list:
        var_list.pop(var_list.index((e["text"]).lower())) #this adds a string to the list
    else:
        var_list.append((e["text"]).lower()) #this deletes the string from the list if it was already there
```

The function works, I tried printing the `var_list` and it gets updated everytime I press a button.
The problem is that I have to create the `var_list` as an empty list before, and when I run the function `analize(var_list)`, it uses the empty list instead of the updated one.

Any idea on how to update the global var everytime I add/delete something from the list?

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk

def show_frame(frame):
    frame.tkraise()

def button_clicked(e):
    if ((e["text"]).lower()) in var_list:
        var_list.pop(var_list.index((e["text"]).lower()))
    else:
        var_list.append((e["text"]).lower())

def analize(x):

    #does stuff with the list

window = Tk()

frame1 = Frame(window)
frame2 = Frame(window)

canvas1 = Canvas(frame1,width = 1280, height = 720)
canvas1.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="background.png")

var_list = []

button1 = Button(canvas1, text="Analize",font=("Arial"),justify=CENTER, width=10, command=lambda: [show_frame(frame2),analize(x=var_list)])
button1.place(x=(1280/2)-42, y=400)

button2 = Button(canvas1, text="String1",font=("Arial"),justify=CENTER, width=10, command=lambda: button_clicked(button2))
button2.place(x=(1280/2)-42, y=450)

button3 = Button(canvas1, text="String2",font=("Arial"),justify=CENTER, width=10, command=lambda: button_clicked(button3))
button3.place(x=(1280/2)-42, y=500)
```

Thank you

Comment: Your description of the problem is unclear. Please [edit] it and add a [mre] (MRE).

Comment: Hi Could you please elaborate your question? Also, to avoid confusion, use variables. Example: you have used ```((e["text"]).lower())``` directly in the ```if``` statement. I recommend using another variable for that and then using the variable in the if statement.

Comment: I got expected/updated result when adding `print(x)` inside `analize()`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can make a global variable eg:-`global var`
Now you can access it within other defination to manipulate the variable like this

```
global var
var = 0 # if you want to set a default value to the variable before calling the 
function

def change_var():
    global var
    var = 1
```

> **USE OF GLOBAL**

using global is highly recommended and is quite necessary if you are working with functions that contain or has the need to manipulate the variable

If global is not given inside the function, the variable will live inside the function and it cannot be accessed outside the function.

Hope this answer was helpful, btw, I am not sure if this the answer you are looking for as your question is not clear, maybe give a situation where you might think it might be necessary to change or update the variable

Comment: I tried it before and didn't work but now it did.. maybe I did something wrong the first time, thank you! (and sorry for the poor explanation)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I did not understand you but I guess this example will help you -

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

var_list = []

def change_val(n):
    var_list.append(n)
    label1.config(text=var_list)

def remove():
    try:
        var_list.pop()
        label1.config(text=var_list)

    except:
        pass

label1 = tk.Label(root,text=var_list)
label1.pack()

button1 = tk.Button(root,text='1',command=lambda:change_val(1))
button1.pack()

button2 = tk.Button(root,text='2',command=lambda:change_val(2))
button2.pack()

button3 = tk.Button(root,text='3',command=lambda:change_val(3))
button3.pack()

button4 = tk.Button(root,text='Pop Element',command=remove)
button4.pack()

root.mainloop()
```